# Need to make Object value optional using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, authentication, jsx

Good Afternoon,
I am building a web app using ReactJS and using Auth0 for Authentication.
I am using state to save the data I need to send to my backend to update a users information. I need to make both key/values optional, I should be able to send the data to my backend with just the updated email or nickname. As it stands right now it requires both. I used Postman to send just one key value to the API to make sure that it is possible and that works.

```js
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    nickname: '',
    email: '',
  });
  
    const updateFunction = () => {

    try {
     fetch(`http://localhost:8080/updateuser`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {"Content-type": "application/json"},
        body: JSON.stringify({id, data})
      })
      .catch((e) => {console.log(e)});


    
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }

     
  }
```

```html
       <GridContainer>
                <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={3}>
                <TextField id="standard-basic" label="Username" onChange={e => setData({...data, nickname: e.target.value})}/>
                </GridItem>
                <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={4}>
                   <TextField id="standard-basic" label="Email Address"  onChange={e => setData({...data, email: e.target.value})}/>
                </GridItem>
              </GridContainer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check to see if the object contains a key value pair that equals an empty string and delete that key before posting it to the api like so:

```
const updateFunction = (data) => {
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
      if (value === "") delete data[key];
    }

    try {
      console.log(data);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  };
```

attached is a sandbox to see it in action: https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-voice-gn1rd?file=/src/App.js:121-347

Comment: This worked, thank you. If you are able can you explain a little bit about the syntax you are using, such as the [key,value] and Object.entries. is the [key,value] a type of destructuring?

Comment: no problem. here is the documentation regarding Object.entries https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries.  It allows you to loops through an objects key-value pairs

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send only one of the value then in the body you can do

```
body: JSON.stringify(
 { name: name.trim().length > 0 ? name : undefined,
   email: email.trim().length > 0 ? email : undefined 
 }
) .
```

Stringifying an object with its value as undefined will remove the entire key from the object .

Now with the above change in place when you have only email filled . You json will be just

```
{ email: .... }
```

`name` will be deleted automatically .